# Get camera model from picture file in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, filesystems, metadata

I hope this isn't a duplicate, but I wasn't able to find something similar.

I was wondering how I could get the picture details for a specific file in windows.[image]

When searching for ways to do this, I was mainly pointed towards the following code, but I'm not sure how to use it/if it's the best option:

```
std::string ImageProcessor::GetCameraType(std::string filePath) 
{
WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fInfo; 
auto stemp = std::wstring(filePath.begin(), filePath.end());
GetFileAttributesEx(stemp.c_str(), GetFileExInfoStandard, &fInfo);
//PrintFileAttributes(fInfo.dwFileAttributes);
}
```

Can I even use these file attributes to get those custom camera details? Or do I need to go about it in another way? (FIY, the picture is a CR2 file)

I'm new to c++ so all help would be helpfull!

Comment: The standard solution is to parse the metadata. The [Windows Imaging Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-lh) provides the infrastructure for that (see [Processing Image Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-metadata-portal)). I'm guessing that .cr2 is based off of TIFF, which the WIC provides native support for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. The most simple is to use the [Shell API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellitem2) and query for the [System.Photo.CameraModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-photo-cameramodel) property, something like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shobjidl_core.h>
#include <propkey.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    IShellItem2* item;
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"c:\\path\\photo.jpg", NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&item))))
    {
        LPWSTR str;
        if (SUCCEEDED(item->GetString(PKEY_Photo_CameraModel, &str)))
        {
            wprintf(L"Model: %s\n", str);
            CoTaskMemFree(str);
        }
        item->Release();
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```